# Can't flag for moderators while suspended, when plagiarism goes on

Tags: support, account-suspension, plagiarism

I'm suspended on Stack Overflow for a while so I can't post a comment to flag for attention of the mods on Stack Overflow. Not sure how to deal with it. The reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47274897/1525840) is a copy of one I've got about a year ago. The user seems to simply have copied the text.

What should I do?

Comment: As far as I can see, that answer does not duplicate the syntax of any previous answers.

Comment: @Shog9 Not sure what you mean. The point of the linked answer copies the point of the answer right above it.

Comment: The syntax is visibly different, @Konrad. Quite possibly *incorrect*, but if nothing else different. Neither one answers your question very well, so I'd wager both are the result of folks trying to do something else stumbling across your question based on the title and dropping their solutions in.

Comment: The answers are both different. If you look closely you will see that there is a light change of wording and a new[] in the brackets

Answer (score 11):

That is right, while suspended you can't perform any action on the site. That's on purpose. Being suspended means you broke some basic rules and can't be trusted for a while. This includes flagging.

> What should I do?

Nothing. Just wait until the suspension is over.

Comment: If we have a position on copying answers, I doubt it's "feel free to copy answers from people who are suspended." I mean, I get it, a year for voting irregularities, something happened, but if answers are being copied shouldn't there be a way to report that?

Comment: @KateGregory: In this case the OP is trying to report plagiarism from one of the answers to one of their own questions. So presumably the basic crowd-sourced moderation mechanism — whoever sees it reports it — should still work.

Comment: @Kate others can report it as well. For all we know, user was suspended due to abusing flags, so letting them flag is absurd. And starting to check suspension reason and based on that give some permissions is way too complicated for very little gain.

Comment: Abusing flags has nothing to do with my suspension at all. Not sure where you get that assumption from but it's wrong. Also, you seem to miss the point of the question - someone copied an answer from someone else. (I'm the guy who asked the question - the answer and the copy of it is nothing I posted.) My suspension is due in 10 months and I still care about the quality of the site. Any other suggestions? (BTW, I do sound bitter because it's assumptions like yours that got me suspended to begin with. That kind of conduct erodes the reliability of SE/SO, in my opinion.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Given the number of questions, there's no much of a guarantee that someone else than me sees it. I was notified about a new answer when the user posted it. That's the **only** reason I even reviewed it. Since I'm unable to flag it myself, I was wondering what to do. "Do Nothing" seems so contra-productive for the site's quality.

Comment: @KateGregory You can file a DMCA takedown request if someone has violated a copyright of yours.  You can do that even when suspended.  If a post violates the site's standards for copying content, but doesn't break the law, then that would fall under activities that suspended users aren't trusted to report, just like all of the other rules on the site.

Comment: @KonradViltersten When a user is suspended the mod doesn't decide which actions should be prevented based on what the problematic behavior was.  Instead, suspended users have *all* ability to interact with the site removed (outside of the ability to reply to the suspension message).  This is both to avoid putting a heavy burden on mods to try to figure out what should/shouldn't be taken away, but also because users that behave badly enough to merit suspension are likely to lash out via any means left available to them, hence you can't flag even if you weren't suspended for flag abuse.

Comment: @KonradViltersten it's not about you in person, suspension is the same for everyone, the reason is just text. There are no suspension "types" behind the scenes. So those who break voting rules and those who abuse flags have exactly the same suspension rules applied.

Comment: I only react to the assumption of yours (that it was because of the flags). I bear quite a portion of frustration still because it was this kind of assumptions (incorrect ones) that got my behind suspended. "*Those who break voting rules*" should be "*those who modes believe to break voting rules*", in my opinion. It has a touch of arrogance and self-righteousness in my view. On the other hand, I'm biased as I feel wronged, so let's just drop the subject. The OP was about how to flag and the answer is that I can't. (Wise or not, that's another story.)